# Haskell test performance for different container types

Tags: haskell

I want to test the performance for various types of containers in Haskell. So far I got Vector and List.  My goal is to learn how to use typeclass, how to use containers etc. Could anyone point out suggestions of below code?

```
module Lib where

import           Data.Array
import           Data.List
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Radix as R
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed          as V
import           System.CPUTime
import           System.Random
import           Text.Printf

class TestSTL t where
  stlGenerate ::(Random a, V.Unbox a) => Int -> IO (t a) --generate random number of t a
  stlSort :: (Ord a, V.Unbox a, R.Radix a) => t a -> t a
  stlSearchIndex :: (Ord a, V.Unbox a) => a -> t a -> Maybe Int

instance TestSTL [] where
  stlGenerate i = take i . randoms <$> getStdGen
  stlSort l = sort l
  stlSearchIndex = elemIndex

instance TestSTL V.Vector where
  stlGenerate i = V.replicateM i randomIO
  stlSort = V.modify R.sort
  stlSearchIndex = V.elemIndex
-- instance (Ix ix) => TestSTL (Array ix) where
--   stlGenerate i = take i . randoms <$> getStdGen
--   stlSort l = sort l
--   stlSearchIndex = elemIndex


time :: IO a -> IO a
time action = do
  t0 <- getCPUTime
  r <- action
  t1 <- getCPUTime
  let tm :: Double
      tm = fromInteger (t1 - t0) * 1e-9
  printf "%.3f ms\n" tm
  return r

test :: IO ()
test = do
  -- preparation
  putStrLn "Please input an Int:"
  e <- readLn :: IO Int

  -- test list
  putStrLn "Testing List:"
  r <- time
    $ stlSearchIndex e . stlSort
    <$> (stlGenerate 1000000 :: IO [Int])

  case r of
    Just i  -> putStrLn $ "Found at " ++ show i
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Not found"

  -- test vector
  putStrLn "Testing Vector:"

  r' <- time
    $ stlSearchIndex e . stlSort
    <$> (stlGenerate 1000000 :: IO (V.Vector Int))

  case r' of
    Just i  -> putStrLn $ "Found at " ++ show i
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Not found"
```